# Extract .zip Archive to .jar file

Tags: c#, jar, zip, .net

I'm using `System.IO` and `ZipFile`, I was wondering if anyone could give me a snippet of code that extracts files from a .zip archive and puts them into a .jar file, or atleast helps get me started with doing something like that.

Answer (score 0):

JARs are ZIPs just with a different extension, just copy and rename the file.

Answer (score 0):

Jar and zip has exactly same format.
You can add meta-inf to that jar if you want to add some manifest (can be done via JarFile etc)